# workbooks.connections.add2 gives runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've copied all arguments form an existing connection created manually through excel and going into -> connections -> connection -> properties.

My code is below, I'm trying to execute a simple connection to my access database. But I keep getting the error message: runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Code

```
Sub CustomPivotConnection()

    Dim connstring As String: connstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=C:\Users\username\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=;Jet OLEDB:System database=;Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=;Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False"
    Dim cmdstring As String: cmdstring = "'AZN','BOL','Dates','Instruments'"

    Workbooks("WorkbookTester.xlsm").Connections.Add2 _
    "Testing", "Testing", connstring, cmdstring, 6, True, True
End sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether this will help you, but I had a similar error earlier today and fixed it by typing: `OLEDB;` at the start of the connection string. So it read:

`OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft...`

It may help to use the wizard first and look at the connection string it generates; you can then use this in the VBA code.

Comment: This is very similar to the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219298/setting-an-odbc-connection-string-in-vba/28220771#28220771), I think generally, you need to prefix the connection string with its type for both OLEDB and ODBC connections.

Comment: Also, another thing to check when adding "OLEDB;" to the front of your connection string is that your "CmdType" is set correctly, the original question uses 6("xlCmdTableCollection") but that won't work for every connection string, I've found its good to double check the type, to make sure that it is consistent.